# Laravel 5.2 attempting to bind data to a partial view

Tags: laravel-5

I am using using Laravel 5.2 binding data to a partial view. I receive the following error "Object of class Illuminate\View\View could not be converted to int"
with this code in the appServiceProvider boot method:

// binding data to a partial view

```
view()->composer('partials.nav', function($view)
{
$view-with('latest', Article::latest()->first());
});
```

Any thoughts on how I received this error and how I can solve this problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.I'm at the home stretch of these fundamentals :)

Answer (score 0):

replace $view-with with $view->with otherwise it will be interpreted as a minus.